# Why isn't my css working?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress webpage [here](http://budgrid.com/2014/12/lighterbro-the-ultimate-bic-multi-tool/). I've been working on it, testing new plugins, etc and recently part of my CSS code in my child theme folder stopped working. I'm not sure exactly when it happened, so not sure what caused it, but I did not change the code for the CSS or what outputs the bullets. The CSS controls the bullet points at the beginning of the content - CSS below:

```
.highlight-container {
    background:#dddddd;
    float:right;
    padding-right:25px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.highlight-title {
    padding-left:25px;
    padding-top:10px;
    font-size:1.5em;
    margin-bottom:-15px;
    
}

.highlight-list {
    font-size: .75em;
    padding-left:0;
    margin-left:0;
}

.highlight-item {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0.25em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
```

I already tried to deactivate any plugins I installed to check for conflicts in the CSS. Any other ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: to which css files you added these rules?, i mean can you provide the path

Answer (score 0):

One of the points of stackoverflow is to provide details so that it can help the next user who reads your problem. Providing a link to a page where something does not work currently will not help the community in general (refer to the Meta if you can). That said, your style.css has the following rules for the following classes. It looks like you didn't update your code?

```
.highlight-container {
}
.highlight-title {
}
.highlight-list {
}
.highlight-item {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice Duniyadnd, I see your point. Turns out the issue was very strange. When I went to sociallyviral-child/style.css through view-source instead of ftp, I got a bunch of Â characters as the spaces before all my classes. I downloaded the file to notepad, erased and re-entered all the spaces/tabs, and now everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As Duniyadnd say,
you have the css file in this route:
http://budgrid.com/wp-content/themes/sociallyviral-child/style.css?ver=4.0.1
and there are only

```
.highlight-container {
}
.highlight-title {
}
.highlight-list {
}
.highlight-item {
}
```

there is nothing inside

Answer (score 0):

Judging by what you described.

You're using external style sheet for your css.

so it's like

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

When external style sheet css not working.

1. can't find the file.(path is not correct or file deleted)
2. your Inline Style or Internal style sheet overwrite the css properties.

go check them. if it isn't. put more details so people can help you out.